# Using a custom font in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fonts

I know this is a very repeated question. I've tried them, and I don't know why it still doesn't work for me. I'm using a custom theme in bootstrap. And I've added a font called BebasNeue.ttf in the folder where my site's files are.

Here is the code I am trying.

```
<h1 style="color:white; font-family:BebasNeue;"> Some random content!!</h1>
```

In the CSS I have called the font-face property as well.

```
@font-face {
font-family: BebasNeue;
src: url(fonts/BebasNeue.ttf);}
```

It still doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the issue that you are having

use

```
   src:url(fonts/BebasNeue.ttf) format('truetype')
```

that's it done. further if still it did not work then try using  single quotes

```
 @font-face{

font-family:'BebasNeue'
src:url(fonts/BebasNeue.ttf) format('truetype')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading the webpage on IE, then use lowercase letters for the font URL. Uppercase letters can give unexpected results in IE!

[Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp).

Answer (score 0):

```
src: url(../fonts/BebasNeue.ttf);}
```

It's maybe working